# Pass parameter to SSRS report, while initializing a default value

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to pass a new parameter to a SSRS report, therefore I have created 2 methods in the Contract class:

```
    [DataMemberAttribute('LanguageId')]
public LanguageId parmLanguageId(languageId _languageId = languageId)
{

    languageId = _languageId;

    return languageId;
}
```

And another to retrieve the value:

```
    public LanguageId getLanguageId()
{
    return languageId;
}
```

In my DP class I am also retrieving the value:

```
languageId = _contract.getLanguageId();
```

So far, so good, the dialog when running my report is passing through the value with the selected Language ID in my dialog.

The problem I'm having, is when initializing a default value in the dialog, it doesn't pass my selected value, but the default value initialized when opening the dialog.

I was thinking to edit my parmLanguageId like:

```
[DataMemberAttribute('LanguageId')]
public LanguageId parmLanguageId(languageId _languageId = 'DefaultLanguageValue')
{

    languageId = _languageId;

    return languageId;
}
```

But, then comes the part where I have to change the variable to the selected value, I probably miss a simple solution, but how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you just put these into procs and have them resolve before the params that need them and just cascade. Seems easier than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you explain your solution please? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding method `prePromptModifyContract` in your report controller class and adding following lines in it:

```
YourContract contract = this.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract() as YourContract;  
contract.parmLanguageId('DefaultLanguageValue');
```

Comment: I have tried adding this line in the Controller class, but it won't pass the language value to the dialog. When I add a breakpoint and check with the debugger, the language parameter is empty.

Comment: `prePromptModifyContract` is called before the parameter dialog is shown to the user. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in this method, did it work for you? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in `parmLanguageId` of your Contract class to monitor what's happening? Just in case, did you generate CIL after the change?